# Sharing connections Simple.Data.UnresolvableObjectException

Tags: c#, simple.data

I have just plugged in application insights into my azure web role which is using simple data.

In the exception view in Application Insight I am seeing exception's occurring for every database call for both **UseSharedConnection** and **StopUsingSharedConnection**
One thing to note is the query is being completed successfully.

I can see that in the help at  http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/pages/Start/SharingAConnection.html it says this is only supported in ADO Adapter only.

[image: Exception for Use shared Connection]

My repository code looks like this

[image: repository Code]

My Connection String is in the format following.

Server=tcp:.database.windows.net,1433;Database=;User ID=@;Password=;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;

Comment: 1. If you're running on Azure, are you sure you want to use the ADO adapter and not switch up to Azure Table Storage?
2. Are you definitely running v0.18.3.1 of Simple.Data? There was an older syntax for this which you can find at http://blog.markrendle.net/2011/11/24/simple-data-0-11/ but I don't know when \ if it was swapped out

Comment: Thanks, I am definitely using the latest version of simple.data (0.18.3.1). We are not using's Azure's table storage just the hosted Azure SQL service.